# App crashing when trying to create a TBXML object with this xml

Tags: iphone

I am trying to parse following xml using tbxml library -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<REPLY   replyCode="Success" >
<TRACK track_id="1302234"  track_mp3="74-Ruff_Ryders_feat_Sheek_Louch_and_Big_Pun_-_PiÃ±a_Colada.mp3"></TRACK>
</REPLY>
```

But when I tried to create TBXML object the app is crashing I think this is because of some special chars in xml file (PiÃ±a).

Any idea on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latest version 1.4 resolved this problem!!